# Tool to combine Website Graphics into Single Graphic (for CSS Offset Style Backgrounds)

Tags: css

in order to reduce the number of HTTP requests I want to change my CSS to not use 20 different graphics files any more, but instead use 1 file and then change the offset.

However, I find it very difficult to create these files from scratch - is there a developer tool that can create such a combined file for me from a number of source image files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteMe is a JS bookmarklet that is supposed to automage css sprite creation on an existing site. I've heard it's amazing. http://spriteme.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "CSS Sprite Builder" - Google will find you loads.  Here's an online one:

[CSS Sprites - Online CSS Sprite Builder / Generator](http://css-sprit.es/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this C# code:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/554_CSS_Sprites_Merging_Images_to_Achieve_Better_Performance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check that tool (in eng) http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a graphics tool like Paint.NET?
You could use Paint.NET to add each image to a layer, adjust the position of each layer and then flatten all layers into a single image and then store that image on your web server.